# Input format and Output format in Django Rest Framework Seriaizer

Tags: mysql, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Hi my client api will send me char array like=>

```
["user1","user2","user3",...]
```

My model field is CharField like=>

```
emplist = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=False,blank=False)
```

I would like to convert this array input to string in serializer and string output to array in the serializer. Can I do that?

How can I handle this array with any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely handle with a couple of tweaks on your Model.

1. Alter your `emplist` field to become `_emplist`

```
_emplist = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=False, blank=False)
```

2. Add `property` methods to your model for `emplist`

```
@property
def emplist(self):
    return self._emplist.split(',')
@emplist.setter
def emplist(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, list):
        self._emplist = ','.join(value)
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        self._emplist = value
```

3. Now in your Serializer just add `ListSerializer` field to you `emplist` field

```
emplist = serializers.ListSerializer(child=serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False, allow_null=False))
```

And now it is going to work perfectly for this case.

Comment: I tried that way but it get "_emptlist': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')] ". what is different _emplist vs emplist?

Comment: the underscore is just a convention for private fields, I am wrapping it with @property, so you can hook the wrapped property along with the serializer. in order to solve that, just make the `_emplist` with `null=True`, and `blank=True`